# Process Builder is resetting created date on lead

Tags: process-builder

I set up a process to do 3 things, add the last date/time contacted, check a box saying the lead has been contacted by rep and run this formula `FLOOR((NOW()-[Task].CreatedDate )*1440)` to log the number of minutes between receiving the lead and contacting the lead.

The formula always returns 0 because the process is resetting the lead creation date to the `Last Real Activity` date/time.

Why is this happening? Even if the solution is as simple as running the formula first, I'd still like to know why the date and time of creation is being reset?

[image: process]

Comment: You are using Task.CreatedDate. That isn't the lead record.

Comment: @DanielHoechst you're right, I didn't notice. It's built on the task object and I have no way to access the Lead object, maybe I'll need to rethink this. If you want to answer instead of comment then I'll mark as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you have created is referencing the Task.CreatedDate and not the Lead's created date. Since this process fires when the Task is created, it will always be the current date.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can reference the WhoId fields from Process Builder, Flow, or even a formula field. This may be something you need to do with Apex.